# How do I compare values in a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a matrix looks something like this:

```
m = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7, 8],
     [9, 1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

and I wanna compare values to their adjacent values so the function return a bool. For example, if I input `m[1][1]` which is 6, the function should compare 6 with 1,2,3,5,7,9,1 and 2 (cells around 6) and return whether 6 is the largest number. And also if I input an index out of range say `m[0][4]` the function should also return `False`.

I understand how to do this part (kind of), but when it gets to the values on the edges I'm completely stuck. I cannot assume that the matrix is 4x4 (it could be anything, 3x3, nxn) so it is impossible to write out every situation with if statements. What should I do?

Comment: This seems like something `numpy` would be able to do easily

Comment: is it guaranteed to be a square matrix?

Comment: Please post your existing code and more details about what's stopping you. It's hard to help otherwise. You can [edit] the question. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You should do some of the work on this yourself.

Here's some code to get you started:

```
def adjacent_cells(m, row, col):
    result = []
    for i, j in ((-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1),
                 (0, -1),          (0, 1),
                 (1, -1), (1, 0),  (1, 1)):
        try:
            i += row
            j += col
            if i >= 0 and j >= 0:
                result.append(m[i][j])
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return result
```

Use this as a building block to complete your project.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
m = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7, 8],
     [9, 1, 9, 3],
     [4, 5, 6, 7]]

def maxAmongNeighbors(matrix,y,x):
    return (
        x in range(1,len(matrix[0]))
        and y in range(1,len(matrix))
        and matrix[y][x] >= max(
            *matrix[y-1][x-1:x+2],
            *matrix[y][x-1:x+2:2],
            *matrix[y-1][x-1:x+2]
        )
    )

print (maxAmongNeighbors(m,0,0))
print (maxAmongNeighbors(m,1,1))
print (maxAmongNeighbors(m,2,2))
```

> ```
> False
> False
> True
> ```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import numpy as np

def isLargest(input, r,c):
    padded = np.pad(input, 1, mode='constant')
    value = input[r][c]
    r += 1
    c += 1
    if value >= max(padded[r-1][c], padded[r+1][c], padded[r][c-1], padded[r-1][c]):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I used zero padding and solved this problem. Padded matrix will be:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 2 3 4 0]
 [0 5 6 7 8 0]
 [0 9 1 2 3 0]
 [0 4 5 6 7 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

then you can easily check condition. The only thing you should notice is that row and column indices should be incremented by one to map the original value.